# How can I connect to my Amazon EC2 server using a desktop client

Tags: server, amazon-ec2

I've already setup an Amazon EC2 instance running 10.10 and am able to connect to it using the ssh command provided by Amazon. I noticed there is a 'Terminal Server Client' and a 'Remote Desktop Viewer' included with Ubuntu, and I was wondering if it's possible to use either of these to connect to my server. It would be a far more convenient than typing out the rather long ssh command (after first navigating to the directory in which my key is stored).

I've had a few tries at connecting with both of them, but the problem is I don't know what I should be putting in the fields since all the documentation provided by both Amazon and Ubuntu assume I already know what I'm doing with servers.

**Update**: From reading the answers it seems I've left out a crucial piece of information. I wish to administer my server using a terminal. My question is about making the connection process as simple as possible.

Comment: You can ssh into the instance, and install the gnome-desktop, then either allot an elastic IP to that instance, and open up a port from the security groups, or use the public DNS provided by amazon. Ill try it and let you know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I *think* you're asking how you can shorten the following command:

```
ssh -i ~/path/to/your/ssh_key.pem \
   ubuntu@ec2-79-125-64-190.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

That can be accomplished with with edits to `~/.ssh/config`.
The following example ssh config stanza might be helpful:

```
Host myec2server
  IdentityFile /home/USERNAME/ec2/ec2-keypair.eu-west-1.pem
  User ubuntu
  HostName ec2-79-125-64-190.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Now, you can just type `ssh myec2server`. see [man ssh_config](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man5/ssh_config.5.html) for more `ssh_config` tricks.  You can then combine that with another of the answers here and create a launcher with the command:

```
gnome-terminal --execute ssh myec2server
```

Also related, is a new-ish EC2 feature [import-keypair](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-ImportKeyPair.html) that allows you to upload your own public keys.  Then, you can launch new servers with keypairs that you use elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You tend not to run desktop instances (that is the full X/GDM/Gnome stack) on server. That graphics stack eats tons of RAM and that very much equates to money when you're talking about EC2.

In short, I think if you're trying to VNC in, you've probably the wrong end of the stick. You certainly can install X et al on a server and then you can install TightVNC (or other) to provide graphical access over network... But if you're just trying to administer a system, learn to use the console and live without it, or use a webmin solution.

Comment: I'm undeleting this answer because of @Kaustubh's answer. Installing `ubuntu-desktop` on a server just for administration is almost always the wrong thing to do.

Comment: I couldnt agree with you more. Granted that we are spoiled on GUI, but server administration is always best served via command-line, and has infact made me fall in love with the terminal ;)

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just make a launcher? Something that runs:

```
gnome-terminal -e "cd where_your_key_is; your amazon command"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your ec2 instance isn't running a graphical user interface,'Terminal Server Client' and 'Remote Desktop Viewer' are used to connect to graphical sessions on desktop computers.

If you find typing the ssh commands tedious, you can [**set up an alias**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414/how-to-create-a-permanent-alias) to get a shorter command or use @Oli's method to [create a Launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16825/how-can-i-add-and-change-items-in-my-applications-menu) for your Main Menu.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, heres what you do, thanks a lot to [Chipaca](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/5006/chipaca)! I owe you one!

1. ssh into the amazon instance.
2. install the ubuntu-desktop and tightvncviewer: (might need an update before installing)

   `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop tightvncserver`
3. On your local machine install the client:

   `sudo apt-get install xtightvncviewer`
4. On the server type this command to start the server:

   `tightvncserver -geometry 800x600`

   You can change the resolution to suit your need, but 800x600 did the job for me.
5. On your client, type this command:

   `xtightvncviewer -via ubuntu@<YourInstance's-Dns-Or-Ip> -compresslevel 9 -quality 5 :1`

PS: I tried this on `ami-ccf405a5` with a ebs backed storage.
PS1:Pressing F8 in the viewer will show you a menu.