# How do I launch Chromium with multiple tabs open using the main menu?

Tags: 10.10, menu, chromium, tabs

I don't want this to be default behavior for Chromium though.

Comment: What do you mean by "with multiple tabs open"? You mean from your previous browsing session?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to start chromium with multiple tabs open, this is what your command will look like:

```
chromium-browser http://google.com/ http://bing.com/ http://yahoo.com/
```

See *[How can I add and change items in my Applications Menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16825/how-can-i-add-and-change-items-in-my-applications-menu)* on how to create a short-cut.