# How to change Applications Menu Contents

Tags: gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I add and change items in my Applications Menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16825/how-can-i-add-and-change-items-in-my-applications-menu)

In Gnome Applications Menu, I would like to move gEdit, Gnu Emacs, KWrite, Kate, NEdit and Scribes from the Accessories menu, to the Programming menu.

Is there any simple way to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open System -> Preferences -> Main Menu (hope I got it properly translated) and simply drag and drop the elements you want to change.

(EDIT: As Reuben Swartz suggests in a comment below, a quicker way to get to the same place is right click on the Application Menu and then select "Edit Menu").

On a side note, you can even Create a new menu (or menus) and create launchers within any menu -in case you don't want to delete those elements from the Accesories menu, but just want to have duplicate entries-.

Comment: simple, obvious, thx.

Comment: Or you could right click on the application menu and select edit menus. This will get you to the same screen.

Comment: Quicker ;)... indeed an enhancement of my proposal.

Comment: @Reuben Swartz: Hope you don't mind if I add your suggestion to my answer, to keep things compact and clear for future needs.

Comment: Go ahead. We are a community after all :)