# How can I add items to Xfce root menu?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, menu

I'd like to add some items to my Xfce "root menu", see picture for location:

[image]

Searching the web gave a couple of possibilities (different XML files etc), but it appears that Xubuntu has customized it quite a bit. Maybe I just overlooked the settings? I also tried LXmenueditor, which does not access the root menus.

Where is the location of the configs for Xubuntu? Would it be possible to get stock-Xfce right click-on-desktop functionality without breaking anything? By that I mean: right click on desktop and have the Xfce menu instead of going through Xubuntu's submenu to access it.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: use [`menulibre`](https://bluesabre.org/2019/05/31/menulibre-2-2-1-released/), `sudo apt install menulibre`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### versions 11.04 - 13.10

[image]

As the picture shows - "test" is a root menu which has been added.

To do this will require a couple of folders to be created:

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/menus
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/applications
```

Next copy the standard menu template file into the local menus folder

```
cp /etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu/menus/* ~/.config/menus
```

Note - the stock XFCE menu could also be used - I prefer this menu so I've used it in my example:

```
cp /etc/xdg/menus/* ~/.config/menus
```

Now create our *test* menu - its in .desktop file-format

```
leafpad ~/.local/share/applications/test.desktop
```

copy and paste the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=test
Comment=
Icon=acroread
Exec=acroread
Path=
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=false
Categories=X-Xfce-Toplevel;
```

The important bit is the last line - it must have *X-Xfce-Toplevel* as a category

Edit our custom menu:

```
leafpad ~/.config/menus/xfce-applications.menu
```

Add a new entry as shown:

[image]

Finally - lets use the custom menu file:

Right click *Start* and choose properties:

[image]

Choose the custom menu option and navigate and select the custom menu file `~/.config/menus/xfce-applications.menu`

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thx! Would you happen to know how I can get rid of the Menu on Desktop?

Comment: Nevermind! To use just the root menu, I disabled the Desktop Icons in desktop-settings. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

If you're using 4.10 or 4.12, then you can edit the Menu using `alacarte` (screenshot) or `menulibre`.

[image]

You may also have a more dynamic menu experience if you were using `xfce4-whiskermenu`.

See also:

- [How can I add and change items in my Applications Menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16825/how-can-i-add-and-change-items-in-my-applications-menu)
- [How can I have a dash-like search under Xfce?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247408/how-can-i-have-a-dash-like-search-under-xfce/404721#404721)

Comment: Whiskermenu is good, but this topic was about the "root" menu / Desktop Menu

Comment: Sure. Doesn't `alacarte` help with that? And whiskermenu also uses the root menu, is it not?

Comment: Not sure why, but after some reinstall changes with alacarte did not apply to any menu.

Comment: Which version of Xfce? It should work with >= 4.10, but NOT with 4.8.

Comment: 4.10. Alacarte shows options to edit/add menus, but does not apply changes. I must add that my system is pretty messy (transformed ubuntu install to xubuntu, added gnome-shell and i3 etc) - maybe something broke along the way

Comment: I think `alacarte` applies changes automatically when you hit close. Try again. Perhaps try to use a `Custom menu file`: copy the default file to a different location, and edit that. I suspect that it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way adding with Application UI:

1. Right client Application button located in toolbar. The menu, click "Edit Applications"
2. Then popup window shows all Application menus, you can navigate to groups and click the group, click "+" button on the window header, then "Add Launcher"

Answer (score -1):

> right click on destkop and have the XFCE menu instead of going thru
>   Xubuntu's submenu to access it.

From Settings Manager - Desktop - Menus tab - enable the show on right click there.

Not sure about menu editing.

Comment: that menu I want to _change_, even if your option is activated it shows the xfce menu as a submenu

Comment: -1. The answer is not helpful with respect to the question.