# Is it possible to use the Unity Dash search features in a different enviornment, such as XFCE?

Tags: unity-dash, xfce, recoll

I have been using the Unity environment on Ubuntu, and although I enjoy the Unity Dash search feature, I want to move away from Unity to the XFCE environment.

Is it possible to have the same sort of indexed search/ launcher functionality in XFCE? And is it possible to bind it to the Super key, just like in Unity.

The default search bar in XFCE seems to only searched through installed programs, and I cannot seem to bind it to just the Super Key.

Thank You.

Comment: Sure it is, someone just needs to implement it. Some time and effort coupled with knowledge and determination, and you are done!

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/247408/how-can-i-have-a-dash-like-search-under-xfce

Comment: have you tried alt+f3

Comment: thanks for the links to the other questions. It seems that synapse can fill that function, and it also seems that I cannot just use the super key by itself as a shortcut for synapse. thanks