# how to add programs to ubuntu menus

Tags: 12.10, menu

i'm just new to ubuntu and i need to know how to add programs like sublime text to my ubuntu gui menus.  sublime doens't come with an installer - you just download the tar file and extract it.

i tried to follow this post 
**[How can I add and change items in my Applications Menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16825/how-can-i-add-and-change-items-in-my-applications-menu)**

but i couldn't find the menu editor in ubuntu 12.10.

any help would be appreciated. 
thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to install alacarte from the [Ubuntu Software Centre](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/alacarte/) or using:

```
sudo apt-get install alacarte -y
```

The instructions covered in the [question](https://askubuntu.com/a/16830/62364) you linked seem very descriptive for the rest of the process.