# Can I change the image of the icons on my taskbar?

Tags: icons, taskbar

Am I able to change the images of the currently running programs on my taskbar? I have one very useful program with a very ugly and outdated icon and I'd like to change it.

Answer (score 3):

Check this: [Where are the Unity Launcher .desktop files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40931/where-are-the-unity-launcher-desktop-files)

Open the .desktop file you want the icon changed for and there will be a

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=
Name=
Comment=
Exec=
Icon=
```

Obviously the file name behind "Icon=" is what you need to replace. From [UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles):

> Icon field is the icon that should be used by the launcher and represents the application. All icons that are under the directory /usr/share/pixmaps don't need to have their full path specified, but their filename without the extension. For example, if the icon file is /usr/share/pixmaps/wallch.png, then the Icon field should be just 'wallch'. All other icons should have their full path specified.

Answer (score 3):

I use [alacarte](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/alacarte/) to create custom launchers for programs that come without installers or launchers etc.

Simply install using `sudo apt-get install alacarte` or search for it in the software centre.

This program will let you edit icons and create icons for commands or script files.

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16825/how-can-i-add-and-change-items-in-my-applications-menu) is an answer to a similar question with a more in-depth set of instructions on using alacarte.