# Ubuntu 22.04 Firefox Snap breaks KeePassXC integration and other NativeMessaging protocol 25 apps

Tags: snap, firefox-extensions, 22.04, keepassxc

How can I get this back to work ? My whole password manager integration is now broken thanks to snap. People with 1password will have the same problem.

Regarding "duplicate for ppa install over snap" I'll copy my comment: technically yes, but it's a nice hack and ultimately a workaround (and if you're just trying to get some native transport working after upgrading, it is not the thing you'll search for).

Comment: If you mean 22.04; most extensions work perfectly; a number have been reported as not working to Mozilla who are working to resolve a few issues, as was known prior to release of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS & is tracked, and why upgrades are not yet open for existing users. Some *fixes* are expected to land Monday, but most `firefox` fixes will only land when Mozilla deem them ready/stable.

Comment: I'd remove the snap version of Firefox, and install the APT/DEB version. There's plenty of info on how to do that, either here, or via Google.

Comment: The troubleshooting done in https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/keepassxc-with-firefox-snap/27291/2 suggests that Firefox+Snap+KeepassXC worked fine until a couple weeks ago, so don't leap to the conclusion that it's a Snap-caused issue. Voting to close: This seems a known bug, reported or not. If you want it fixed, help troubleshoot it and add useful data to the bug report.

Comment: I'm against closing this for now. In the issue linked this bug exists since over 3 years and for now nothing is resolved. Installing the PPA is a nice hack, but you'll then have to use ESR or beta as no ppa for stable exists from mozilla (using unofficial PPAs for your browser with its credentials is a no go.)

Comment: Another thing is that some people here mention using some kind of snap additon, I just want to use the extension in firefox together with the kasspassxc in my system.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Firefox as a traditional deb packag (without snap) in Ubuntu 22.04 (jammy)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-packag-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22-0)

Comment: @karel technically yes, _but_ it's a nice hack and ultimately a workaround (and if you're just trying to get some native transport working, not the thing you'll search for).

Comment: Aha -- found the upstream bug report: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1661935. There is a fix currently in testing: https://phabricator.services.mozilla.com/D140803 . Once the patch lands in a release of Firefox, snap users will get it right away (snapd checks for updates several times each day).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Update:** [Native messaging support in the Firefox snap is now available as beta](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/call-for-testing-native-messaging-support-in-the-firefox-snap/29759). Beware that this is pretty fresh - the code hasn't been merged upstream, yet, so don't expect this to be production-ready. There is also a [German article by Heise Online](https://www.heise.de/news/Ubuntu-Neue-Schnittstelle-fuer-eingesperrten-Firefox-7194499.html) with a step-by-step guide on how to get this going - in case you want to give it a try.

---

Unfortunately [this issue can't be fixed on KeePassXC's end](https://github.com/keepassxreboot/keepassxc/issues/7022) and so far neither [Flatpak](https://github.com/flatpak/xdg-desktop-portal/issues/655) nor [Snap](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1661935) support NativeMessaging, yet (their sandboxing techniques prevent the browser extension from talking to the KeePassXC process). While work on a solution is in progress, all we can do is work around this issue (or switch to a distro which still provides browsers as regular packages like Debian). The [KeePassXC Troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/keepassxreboot/keepassxc-browser/wiki/Troubleshooting-guide) recommends installing the browser from the official PPA. This isn't pretty but the following approach worked for me:

1. Uninstall the Firefox snap

   ```
   sudo snap remove firefox
   ```
2. Ubuntu provides a transitional `firefox` Debian package which installs the Snap. We need to ensure that packages from Mozilla's PPA have higher priority (otherwise `apt` might "upgrade" to the Snap again).

   ```
   echo '
   Package: firefox
   Pin: release o=LP-PPA-mozillateam
   Pin-Priority: 1001
   ' | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla-firefox
   ```

   If you are using unattended-upgrades you also need to run the following to ensure unattended-upgrades takes the Mozilla PPA into account:

   ```
   echo 'Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins:: "LP-PPA-mozillateam:${distro_codename}";' | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/51unattended-upgrades-firefox
   ```
3. Install Firefox from Mozilla's PPA:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install firefox
   ```
4. Disable AppArmor for Firefox to ensure the Firefox extension can connect to KeepassXC:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.firefox /etc/apparmor.d/disable/
   sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.firefox
   ```
5. Run `KeePassXC` and enable browser integration (menu Tools -> Settings -> Browser Integration, tick "Enable browser integration" and "Firefox").
6. Run `Firefox`, open settings of the KeePassXC extension -> Connected Databases -> Connect.

### Disclaimer

This approach has the drawback that AppArmor is disabled completely - beware that this weakens security. Maybe someone with more AppArmor experience can contribute a safer way to get NativeMessaging working again?

### Troubleshooting

A few tips in case you run into issues:

- You can check whether you are running the Snap version or the regular version of Firefox by opening Help -> About Firefox. If the version number doesn't mention "Snap" you are running the regular version:
  [image]
- You can check the apt priorities by running `apt-cache policy firefox`. Verify that the Mozilla PPA has higher priority than the official Ubuntu repository. The output might look like this:

  ```
  $ apt-cache policy firefox
  firefox:
    Installed: 101.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.22.04.1~mt1
    Candidate: 101.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.22.04.1~mt1
    Version table:
       1:1snap1-0ubuntu2 500
          500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
  *** 101.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.22.04.1~mt1 1001
          500 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
          100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
  ```

Comment: I just tested it on my machine and it looks to me that both downsides are not an issue (anymore?): The package `firefox` Mozilla Team PPA has version 100 of Firefox, while the ESR version is in a separate package - `firefox-esr`. I also did not have to do anything in regards to AppArmor in order to get KeePassXC to work with Firefox. It looks like a usable `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.firefox` is part of the `firefox` package from the PPA.

Comment: In my current setup (Ubuntu 22.04.1, Firefox 115 from snap, KeePassXC 2.7.5), everything works right out of the box. No need to subscribe to any beta channel anymore.

Comment: @BobAidenScott well, for me it doesn't work. I can't connect Firefox to KeePassXC. Is your KeePassXC from snap as well? Mine (2.7.4) is from the Ubuntu package repo.

Comment: @blubberdiblub I use both Firefox and KeepassXC from snap.

Comment: Firefox Snap __beta__, KeePassXC snap and KeePassXC Browser extension work fine for me for a while. AFAIK https://phabricator.services.mozilla.com/D140803 needs to be merged to switch to Firefox Stable snap channel.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer to use [the Firefox Snap Beta with native messaging support (as mentioned by others)](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/call-for-testing-native-messaging-support-in-the-firefox-snap/29759), over the other alternatives which also have their drawbacks. Install it with:

`sudo snap refresh firefox --beta`

On a fully updated Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, I did not have to do any additional steps mentioned in the Heise [article](https://www.heise.de/news/Ubuntu-Neue-Schnittstelle-fuer-eingesperrten-Firefox-7194499.html), such as `systemctl --user restart xdg-desktop-portal`.

The Firefox beta *(105.0b3)* works well with KeePassXC *(2.7.1)* from the [official PPA](https://keepassxc.org/download/#linux) and the Firefox KeePassXC-Browser extension *(version 1.8.1)*. Other KeePassXC packages did not work for me. Install KeePassXC with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phoerious/keepassxc
sudo apt update
sudo apt install keepassxc
```

Comment: Works perfectly!

Comment: Just tested on Ubuntu (Mate) 22.04 and this works. Just an additional step was needed, as explained in the troubleshooting page https://github.com/keepassxreboot/keepassxc-browser/wiki/Troubleshooting-guide#5-ubuntu-snap.
`flatpak permission-set webextensions org.keepassxc.keepassxc_browser snap.firefox yes`

Comment: This works fine with both Firefox 119.0b4 snap and KeePassXC 2.7.5 snap on Ubuntu 22 LTS.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to the other answer (without PPA), simply use the official version from [mozilla.org](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/).

It can be used as  static/portable installation, the executable is `path/to/firefox/firefox`. It can also be installed system-level as said [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-firefox-linux#w_install-firefox-from-mozilla-builds-for-advanced-users) (as per comment by @mook75), something which copies that folder to `/opt`, creates needed symlinks (so that a command like `firefox` starts the browser), and provides a launcher.

Testing in 22.04 (portable) I have found no limitations compared to the previous non-snap version, all addons work, there is just the fact that update has to be done with a click in `Help - About Firefox`.

[image: screenshot]

With portable install we need to create a launcher for it, manually or with a menu editor like [Alacarte](https://askubuntu.com/a/16830/925128) or KDE Menu Editor.

Comment: Since the tarball doesn't include any instructions how to install, [this](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-firefox-linux) might be helpful.

Comment: @mook - just curious - Are there advantages in installing it (which is nothing but moving firefox folder to `/opt` by  `mv firefox /opt `) over keeping the `firefox` folder  anywhere? Does the system starts prompting for updates or something?

Comment: I don't know, I didn't test it, I installed firefox from mozilla team ppa. I just wanted to add the link to the instructions. I guess that there are many users around not knowing what to do with the tarball.

Comment: @mook765 - my installation is local (`~/Applications`), and no update prompt will be gained. But creating needed symlink a command like `firefox` starts the browser etc.

Comment: thanks! didn't even knew there are static builds of ff

Answer (score 1):

I really dislike snap, so I decided to uninstall and [use apt](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04)

KeepassXC browser integration was working with the snap version, but not with apt version. So, I tried to revert, and it was no longer working with snap.

Hours later, I solved it and managed to have **the Firefox apt version connecting with KeepassXC without deactivating the apparmor protection**. I primarily based my solution on the [KeepassXC Troubleshoot](https://github.com/keepassxreboot/keepassxc-browser/wiki/Troubleshooting-guide#6-apparmor-with-ubuntu):

1. . Add the rules below to `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.firefox` just somewhere before you encounter the first profile (in my case it is called `profile lsb_release`):

```
  # Native Messaging
  owner @{HOME}/.mozilla/**/native-messaging-hosts/** ixr,
  /usr/bin/keepassxc-proxy ixr,
  /run/user/1000/org.keepassxc.KeePassXC.BrowserServer ixr,
  /run/user/1000/app/org.keepassxc.KeePassXC/org.keepassxc.KeePassXC.BrowserServer wr,
```

(DISCLAIMER: no idea how important is the place where you add this)

2. Save the file and restart apparmor

```
sudo service apparmor restart
```

3. Restart Firefox, if necessary.

## Still not working?

If your problem is associated to apparmor, you will find the errors in the syslog:

1. Try to connect keepassXC from Firefox (to make sure that the error is at the end of the syslog)
2. Search for errors associated to syslog: `tail -n 100 /var/log/syslog | grep keepass`
3. Or to Firefox: `tail -n 100 /var/log/syslog | grep firefox`

[This comment](https://github.com/keepassxreboot/keepassxc/issues/3096#issuecomment-517974625) helped me get an idea of what is happening.

Comment: Did you find a way to use https://extensions.gnome.org/ with Firefox from the PPA and apparmor enabled? You have to `sudo apt install gnome-browser-connector` and install https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/gnome-shell-integration/ to be able to manage Gnome Extensions in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Just wait :)

This is a known issue, and a fix is underway, expected somewhere in June

See the Native messaging section here:
https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-are-we-improving-firefox-snap-performance-part-1

**UPDATE**

AFAICS this is fixed now.

Not sure if the KeePassXC integration is already working, but other native-messaging apps are.

Just check them with:

`flatpak permissions webextensions`

And add a permission with:

`flatpak permission-set webextensions xx.yy.zz snap.firefox yes`

Comment: that's not a solution / answer

Comment: It's almost September now, and there is now fix

Comment: Firefox Snap __beta__, KeePassXC snap and KeePassXC Browser extension work fine for me for a while. AFAIK https://phabricator.services.mozilla.com/D140803 needs to be merged to switch to Firefox Stable snap channel.

Answer (score 0):

Earlier answers are no longer relevant as [Native Messaging support arrived in Stable Version of Firefox Snap around November 2022.](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/11/firefox-snap-native-messaging-take-two) Firefox snap is now unlikely to be the cause of the browser integration failure.

Ubuntu software app might install keepassxc as a snap and keepassxc snap does not support native messaging (and seems unlikely to do so anytime soon). If so, remove the snap version and [reinstall keepassxc as a ppa](https://keepassxc.org/download/#linux) for browser integration to work.

- Remove keepassxc using Ubuntu Software app
- `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phoerious/keepassxc`
- `sudo apt update`
- `sudo apt update`
- Start keepassxc and go to `Tools` -> `Settings` -> `Browser Integration`
- Select `Enable browser integration` and `Firefox`)

[image]

Comment: Firefox Snap __beta__, KeePassXC snap and KeePassXC Browser extension work fine for me for a while. AFAIK https://phabricator.services.mozilla.com/D140803 needs to be merged to switch to Firefox Stable snap channel.